# Trouble with accessing helpers from mailers in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper

I am using Rails 3.0.3. I tried using all of the methods in the multiple questions on this site that were this question, but I still can't seem to access my helper methods from my mailer. I tried using the 'helper :application' as follows:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "lalala@lalala.com>"

  helper :application
end
```

I also tried 'helper ApplicationHelper' as well as 'add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)'. There is nothing wrong with the helper methods which work just fine for views. Is there something I am missing? Maybe a line in the mailer setup file or something? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Make sure you choose your accepted answers for your questions

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/highlight-changes-being-made-on-activerecord-object-inside-mail/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    include ApplicationHelper

.
.

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `helper :application`, use `extend ApplicationHelper`. `include ApplicationHelper` does not work, at least in Rails 3.2.